# Падает программа с использованием pandas?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pandas, qt-designer

Пытаюсь сравнить 2 *excel* фала с помощью *pandas*, но как только нажимаю кнопку сравнить программа пдает с ошибкой:

> Process finished with exit code 1073741845

Думал, что неверно прописывается путь, но в переменной он есть. 
В чём может быть дело?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import pandas as pd


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(775, 374)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 50, 91, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 240, 121, 21))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 191, 20))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 120, 91, 23))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 190, 91, 23))
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 80, 191, 20))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 150, 191, 20))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 40, 341, 41))
    self.textEdit.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.textEdit.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
    self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(True)
    self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 341, 41))
    self.textEdit_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.textEdit_2.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
    self.textEdit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
    self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
    self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit_3.setEnabled(True)
    self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 341, 41))
    self.textEdit_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.textEdit_3.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
    self.textEdit_3.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
    self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 775, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
      def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сравнить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))


    class ShowPath(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.getFileName1)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.getFileName2)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.comparison)

    def getFileName(self):
        global filename
        filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.textEdit.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename, filetype))

    def getFileName1(self):
        global filename1
        filename1, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit_2.clear()
        self.textEdit_2.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename1, filetype))

    def getFileName2(self):
        filename2, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выбрать файл", ".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit_3.clear()
        self.textEdit_3.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename2, filetype))

    def comparison(self):
        df1 = pd.read_excel(filename)
        df2 = pd.read_excel(filename1)

        difference = df1[df1 != df2]
        print(difference)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.getFileName1)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.getFileName2)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.comparison)

    def getFileName(self):
        global filename
        filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.textEdit.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename, filetype))

    def getFileName1(self):
        global filename1
        filename1, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit_2.clear()
        self.textEdit_2.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename1, filetype))

def comparison(self):
        df1 = pd.read_excel(filename)
        df2 = pd.read_excel(filename1)

        difference = df1[df1 != df2]
        print(difference)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста аккуратнее предоставляйте свой пример:

- указывайте импорты, которые вы используете
- код должен быть правильно отформатирован
- не задваивайте текст

Глобальные переменные - это зло. Сделайте переменную атрибутом класса и работайте с ней в любом методе класса.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import pandas as pd


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(775, 374)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 50, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 240, 121, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 191, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 120, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 190, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 80, 191, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 150, 191, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 40, 341, 41))
        self.textEdit.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 341, 41))
        self.textEdit_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.textEdit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 341, 41))
        self.textEdit_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit_3.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.textEdit_3.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 775, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сравнить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить 2"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить 3"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))


class ShowPath(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.getFileName1)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.getFileName2)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.comparison)
        
        self.filename = None                                            # +++
        self.filename1 = None                                           # +++
        self.filename2 = None                                           # +++

    def getFileName(self):
# -        global filename
        self.filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(        # +++ self.filename
            self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.textEdit.appendHtml(f"<b>{self.filename}</b>")

    def getFileName1(self):
# -        global filename1
        self.filename1, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(      # +++ self.filename1
            self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit_2.clear()
        self.textEdit_2.appendHtml(
            "<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(self.filename1))

    def getFileName2(self):
        self.filename2, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(     # +++ self.filename2
            self, "Выбрать файл", ".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
        self.textEdit_3.clear()
        self.textEdit_3.appendHtml(
            "<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(self.filename2))

    def comparison(self):
        if not self.filename or not self.filename1:                            # +++
            # + здесь надо выдать предупреждение что какой-то файл не выбран   # +++
            return                                                             # +++
            
        df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename)
        df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1)
        print(f'df1 = \n{df1}\n') #
        print(f'df2 = \n{df2}\n') #
        print(f'\ndf1 != df2 = \n{df1 != df2}\n\n') #

        difference = df1[df1 != df2]
        print(difference)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = ShowPath()  
    w.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, полностью согласен, глобальные переменные плохо просто не знал как на python обойтись без них благодаря вам теперь знаю. Обязательно буду придерживаться ваших рекомендаций по выкладыванию кода в вопросе.